# Which _conic_ _sections_ are compact $?$

Tags: geometry, compactness

A  “conic section” in  $\mathbb R^2 $  given  by  a  second  degree  polynomial  $$ ax^2+by^2+2cx+2dy+2hxy=0 $$  .

To  find  whether  they  are  compact  or  not .

But they  are  compact  if  *circle*,*ellipse* and   not  compact  if *parabola* , *hyperbola* , *straight*  *line* .  etc. 
 So  what  is  the  general  result  $?$

Comment: Check whether the quadratic form $ax^2+by^2+2hxy$ is definite. Do you know how to do that? (It is often explained when studying extremums of multivariable functions).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : No  , I  don't  know   how  to  do  that .

Comment: Alternatively check that the eigenvalues of the matrix
$$\pmatrix{a&h\cr h&b\cr}$$ both have the same sign. You should explain your background a bit to get a useful answer. Where I teach the definiteness of bivariate quadratic forms is covered before introducing the concept of a compact set, but this varies world wide.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  :  Actually  ,  I  was  taught  compactness  in  metric  space  and  then  topology  classes . I  have  learnt   some   linear  algebra in  totally  different   classes  so  I   know ,although  not  much ,  about  eigenvalues  and  eigenvectors   and  definite  matrices .  Do  you   advise   that  I  should   read  bivariate  quadratic forms  before  attempting  this  question $?$  This  question  was  in  my  topology  book.  Probably  ,  they  had  then  assumed  that  we  already  learnt  bivariate  things .

Comment: you do not need to know much. All conic sections, including the degenerate ones, are unbounded except for: ellipse, one-point ellipse, and empty ellipse. In turn, these all fit your $ab-h^2 > 0.$  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Matrix_notation   ..... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections